# bootstrap-toggle checkbox is not showing up as toggle

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular, and added bootstrap-toggle using bower. I also included the appropriate css, and js files in my index.html. In my resource file, I need to create a toggle switch. I include the following line:

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
</div>
```

I don't want to add this line using javascript. It is showing up as a checkbox rather than a toggle. Is there something that I am missing? 
[css link snapshopt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJZ58.png)
[js links snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYweL.png)

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? If you are using, Bootstrap v2.3.2, then you should be using `bootstrap2-toggle.min.js` and `bootstrap2-toggle.min.css`.

I just tried it over here and it is working. 
https://jsbin.com/kuqaparayi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I am using 3.3.4. I had also tried with bootstrap2-toggle.min.js and css. But that still didn't work.

Comment: If you are using that, then just use the normal, current version of the bootstrap-toggle. Make sure you load the script tag at the bottom of your body element.

Comment: I am doing that. I think it's not able to find the css file correctly. I have added the css at the top under <head>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, Bootstrap v2.3.2, then you should be using `bootstrap2-toggle.min.js` and `bootstrap2-toggle.min.css`.

Make sure you load the `bootstrap-toggle.css` after the main bootstrap.css file.

Also, make sure load the `bootstrap-toggle.js` after the main bootstrap.js. right before you close the body tag.

Don't forget the jquery, it needs to go before both js files.

Comment: Take a screenshot of your page syntax and share the link.

Comment: Added the image links

Comment: Try commenting out some of the libraries to see if there is any conflicting occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

I have fixed the issue by loading `jquery` and `bootstrap` js files before `bootstrap toggle` js.

Same for css files. First `bootstrap css` and then `bootstrap toggle css`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to include the `.min.css` and `.min.js` since these versions are minified meaning **all whitespace removed to reduce file size and increase speed**.

Firstly include jquery JS.

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
```

You need to include bootstrap-toggle.min.css after the main bootstrap.min.css file.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<link href='https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Then also include, bootstrap-toggle.min.js followed by bootstrap.min.js.

```
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js'></script>
```

Now your checkbox will work as a toggle-checkbox.